# ng-repeat filter not filtering out null values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The JSON :

```
$scope.results=[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: null,
        class: "First"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: John,
        class: "First"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: Mary,
        class: "Second"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: null,
        class: "Third"
    }

]
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 form-group" data-ng-repeat="item in results| filter:{name:'!null'}">{{item.name}}</div>
```

I wanted to filter out the data that has `name` with value `null`.What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Solved by giving data-ng-repeat="item in results| filter:{name:'!!'}".Is there any other solution?

Comment: add ng-show="item.name"

Comment: @MANOJ I think so it is correct solution..

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri Algazin.But that would add more code.I wanted to filter it out using "filter" keyword

Comment: @MANOJ even filter:{name:'!null'} is also working for me. Did you check your results properly??

Comment: @shreya I tried by giving filter:{name:'!null'}.Its not working

Comment: But for me its giving me the same result as filter:{name:'!!'} gives.I am surprised.

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: @shreya.You are correct.Its working the other way round as you said.Checked with Punith's plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your json formate is not proper try this

plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/H94f6XhyyhbvJ3F25NoA?p=preview

```
$scope.results=[
{
    id: 1,
    name: null,
    class: "First"
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
    class: "First"
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: "Mary",
    class: "Second"
},
{
    id: 4,
    name: null,
    class: "Third"
}
];
```

Comment: In your plunker if I print {{item.id}},it will display id's which have name as null.For this purpose I'm using filter  data-ng-repeat="item in results| filter:{name:'!!'}"

Comment: @MANOJ now check my plunker

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this piece of code:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 form-group" data-ng-repeat="item in results| filter:{name:'!!'}">{{item.name}}</div>
```